# ember.js, how can I display data after the page has loaded?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am really new in emberjs but i really want to learn more about it.
I am building a webapp with ember and ember-data.

So, the question is as follows. I have a page (users), that should display all of the objects users, defined in models/users.js . Now, as far as I understand emberjs, the page wait the answer (in my case rest api) before load any data in the handlebars {{outlet}}, I want to know if it is possible to load the page and (image,css etc) and them display the data?

```
==my users.hbs
{{#each user in controller}}
 <li>{{user.name}} - {{user.email}}</li>
{{else}}
 <li>no users… :-(</li>
{{/each}}

==usersRoute.js
    App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return $.getJSON('/REST_API/users').then(function(data){
            return data.body;
        });
    }  
});

==usersController.js
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   sortProperties: ['name'],
   sortAscending: true // false = descending
});

==user.js (model)
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name         : DS.attr(),
    email        : DS.attr()
});

==store
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
App.store = DS.Store.extend()

==router
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('users', function(){
        this.resource('user', { path:'/:user_id' }, function(){
            this.route('edit');
        });
        this.route('create');
    });
});
```

What im want to do is load the page while getting the data and put then in my controller

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model` method will block the rendering until the promise is resolved. You can use the `setupController` so the template will be rendered, and when the data is fetched from ajax, the `each` will rerender because we set with `controller.set('model', data.body);`.

**usersRoute.js**

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller){
        $.getJSON('/REST_API/users').then(function(data){
            // ajax callback is detached from runloop, so we attach again
            Ember.run(function() {
                controller.set('model', data.body);
            });              
        });
    }
});
```

**users.hbs**

```
{{#each user in model}}
 <li>{{user.name}} - {{user.email}}</li>
{{else}}
 <li>no users… :-(</li>
{{/each}}
```